# Can not define value for Object in addEventListener / Creating Object Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to achive something like this:

1. Get elements have same class (`querySelectorAll`)
2. Use these elements `href` attr to get links.
3. Use these links to check these remote images' height and width.
4. Pack them as object and push it declared array.

But, I can not get values from `img.addEventListener("load", function(){})`
Values are in there, if I check `console.log(this.naturalWidth)` but `undefined` outside that function.

Right now, I got nearly 20 tabs opened on StackOverflow about "JS Scope" but it doesn't make sense for my situation.

Note: I'm trying to make this **without jquery**.

```
var pselemgroup = document.querySelectorAll(pselemgroupname);

for(var j = 0; j < pselemgroup.length; j++){

    var obj = new Object();
    var href = pselemgroup[j].href;

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = pselemgroup[j].href;
    img.addEventListener("load", function(){
        obj = {
            src: href,
            w: this.naturalWidth,
            h: this.naturalHeight
        };
        console.log(obj);
    });
    //pselemgroup[j].dataset.index = j;
    galleryElements.push(obj);
}
```

Also this is not about actual question but:
When I try to get `href` value, I got an error about `href`.

After an hour I learned that `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, not Array. So I also tried:

`[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(pselemgroupname));`

and changed some of the code like that:

`pselemgroup[j]["href"]`

but no luck.

Thank you.

### Edit:

So it works when I use galleryElements.push(obj) inside load function but, my ultimate goal was create an array that contains objects.

Like:

```
var items = [
    {
        src: "foo",
        w: "bar",
        h: "baz"
     },
    {
        src: "foo",
        w: "bar",
        h: "baz"
     },
]
```

I can access that objects like `items[0].src` but I . cant access my `galleryElements[]` array objects with the same way. I got error says:

```
undefined.src
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pselemgroup[j]["href"]` instead of `pselemgroup[j].["href"]`

Comment: try `galleryElements.push(obj);` on your `load` function

Comment: @Vivick yep, thats a typo when I create this post. It was not like that in original script. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Not only scope is important here, the listeners get execute when the image is loaded completely, so you should only fill the galleryElements with those images

Comment: @Durga I edited my question. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: you are getting undefined for `galleryElements`, guess you are not defined this where you assessing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well part of your problem is your lack of understanding how the eventlistener works and when your object will be filled or not.

Eventlisteners run in an async way, so, you cannot assume that the object you filled in the callback is filled outside of that scope.

An easy way to go around that would be to make use of the `Promise` object.

You could change your code easily enough to the following

```js
// loads the image and resolves when ready, containing the information you wanted to receive from the image
function loadImageFromUrlAsync( url, text ) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    image.addEventListener('load', () => resolve({
      title: text,
      width: image.naturalWidth,
      height: image.naturalHeight
    } ) );
  });
}

function loadAllImagesBySelectorAsync( selector ) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll( selector ),
      loaders = [], gallery = [];
    for (let element of elements) {
      // after the image is loaded the result gets pushed in your gallery
      loaders.push( 
        loadImageFromUrlAsync( element.href, element.innerText )
        .then( result => gallery.push(result) )
      );
    }
    // this will only go into resolve after all images are loaded
    Promise.all( loaders ).then( () => {
      resolve( gallery );
    });
  });
}

loadAllImagesBySelectorAsync('.image-link').then( gallery => {
  // writes the content of the gallery to the result div
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = gallery
    .map( item => `${item.width}px + ${item.height}px for ${item.title}` )
    .join('<br />');
});
```

```html
<a class="image-link" href="https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.x0SJKpQsIUBt0asGiBa-iwEsDh&pid=15.1&P=0&w=232&h=175">Image 1</a>
<a class="image-link" href="https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.wFyOf5HQmlo2j9p39nTbogEsC7&pid=15.1&P=0&w=279&h=175">Image 2</a>
<a class="image-link" href="https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.SV38MmYJt0TbuZpJMM1mtwEsDI&pid=15.1&P=0&w=255&h=171">Image 3</a>
<a class="image-link" href="https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.s2uDayjT1fqnoT921zfsQwDhEs&pid=15.1&P=0&w=300&h=300">Image 4</a>
<a class="image-link" href="https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.cZ12zxh0UKEsf3Y1_GaReQDHEs&pid=15.1&P=0&w=300&h=300">Image 5</a>

<div id="result"></div>
```

However if you do not want to do such extensive changes to your current code, we can also change it like this, in this case you would have a function with a callback that will be called once all images are loaded

I tried to comment the changes in the code, hope that will be enough

```js
function loadMyGallery(pselemgroupname, callback) {
  // move all variable declaration per function
  // to the top, as var is function scoped
  var pselemgroup = document.querySelectorAll(pselemgroupname),
    j, img, galleryElements = [];

  for (j = 0; j < pselemgroup.length; j++) {

    img = new Image();
    img.src = pselemgroup[j].href;
    img.addEventListener("load", function( href ) {
      // push in the load method
      galleryElements.push({
        title: this.src,
        width: this.naturalWidth,
        height: this.naturalHeight
      });
      // call the callback when you loaded as many images as you found in the pselemgroup.length
      if (galleryElements.length === pselemgroup.length) {
        callback( galleryElements );
      }
      // bind img as the this context
    }.bind(img));
  }
  if (pselemgroup.length === 0) {
    // no elements
    setTimeout( callback, 0 );
  }
}

// load the gallery
loadMyGallery( '.image-link', ( gallery ) => {
  // writes the content of the gallery to the result div
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = gallery
    .map( item => `${item.width}px + ${item.height}px for ${item.title}` )
    .join('<br />');
});
```

```html
<a class="image-link" href="https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.x0SJKpQsIUBt0asGiBa-iwEsDh&pid=15.1&P=0&w=232&h=175">Image 1</a>
<a class="image-link" href="https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.wFyOf5HQmlo2j9p39nTbogEsC7&pid=15.1&P=0&w=279&h=175">Image 2</a>
<a class="image-link" href="https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.SV38MmYJt0TbuZpJMM1mtwEsDI&pid=15.1&P=0&w=255&h=171">Image 3</a>
<a class="image-link" href="https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.s2uDayjT1fqnoT921zfsQwDhEs&pid=15.1&P=0&w=300&h=300">Image 4</a>
<a class="image-link" href="https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.cZ12zxh0UKEsf3Y1_GaReQDHEs&pid=15.1&P=0&w=300&h=300">Image 5</a>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Looks like I have to study about event listeners more, like how they are async and ofc a litttle promises and callbacks. Thank you for your answer, I'm accepting it as answer.